# How to write unit test for code that depends on imported module

Tags: python, unit-testing

Having file with following content

```
import something

if something:
   # do some things here
else:
    raise Exception
```

How can I write unit test that covers `else` branch of file above?

Comment: Is there some other code that could set `something` to `None` or some other false value? If not, then you can probably delete the else branch instead of trying to test it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to "unimport" a module in your test. You can delete the reference from namespace by:

```
del something
```

True, it won't get to the else block. Then you could rewrite the main module with a try-except block as below.

```
try: 
    if something: 
        print "Yes" 
except NameError: 
    print "Something not imported"
```

Comment: That would raise a `NameError`, not run the else branch.